# issues with fglrx and catalyst - have there been changes?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have never had any issues with AMD proprietary drivers, but is seems maybe something has changed in Ubuntu that is causing issues?

When switching to proprietary drivers the computer returns from reset saying it cannot detect the graphics set up. I have options to look at some logs and drop to to tty.

Have tried fglrx and fglrx-updates, both the same. Have downloaded catalyst and compiled manually from terminal for good measure - when I do this I can get to log in, but there after just get a blank screen and a cursor.

Anyone else having issues? Never had anything like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out that you need to install the latest beta drivers from AMD to get this working if you are running x-org 1.14 or above.

Type

```
X -version
```

in a terminal and you will see what version you have. if 1.14 or higher you need to go get the current beta drivers from AMD, which at time of writing is AMD Catalyst™ 13.11 LINUX Beta V9.95 Driver:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx

Download, install, all will be fine.